# GitExtensions - Gource plugin

Tags: windows, git, git-extensions, gource

So I'm using GitExtensions as GUI for Git, and wanted to visualize my repo with the help of Gource.

But eventhough I installed it correctly, and set the  "Path  to 'gource'" accordingly, GitExtensions still is unable to find it.

> Error message: 'Cannot find "gource" in the configured path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Gource. Do you want to reset the  configured
>   path?

GitExtensions Version 2.48.05
Git Version 1.9.4.msysgit.1
Gource Version 0.42
Windows 10 64-bit
Gource install path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Gource

Comment: Also tried already to update GitExtension  and reinstall Gource a couple of times, also to a different path like C:\Gource

Comment: Gource used to work for me, but now it's dead, though I have it installed and configured correctly. GitExtensions doesn't do anything when "gource" is clicked in menu. However I can still call it from CLI. I think it's something is broken in GitExtensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known *GitExtensions* bug ([#3345](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3345)). It'll be fixed in *GitExtensions* 2.49.